# How to avoid killing a thread until its child threads are finished?

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpool, python-multithreading

I am developing my school project and it requires to stop killing thread by itself until its child threads are finished. The following code is a sample that simulates my scenario.

`Sample` is a thread class. It creates a few child threads in its run function. This sample class thread should not be killed until its child threads are finished. So I used `.join()` here.

`Sample` class has another function called `triggrFunction()` which will be triggered through an event call. Once this function is called it will create another child thread. If it creates a thread, `Sample` class thread should not be killed until that child thread is finished. (Sample class thread should be waiting until its all child threads are finished)

So how do I add newly created thread to `self.threadList`, or is there a better way to achieve my requirement ?

```
class Sample(threading.Thread):    
    
    def run(self):        

        for trd in self.threadList:            
            trd.start()

        for trd in self.threadList:            
            trd.join()
            
    def triggrFunction(self):
        #This function will be called through an event call
        
        # Do something
        
        # create a new thread
```

Comment: Can we be sure that `triggrFunction()` will not be called if `run()` has exited?

Comment: @quamrana it can be called at anytime. but definitely after called  run function

Comment: @quamrana My requirement is to stop finishing run function if triggrFunction() called and creates an thread

Answer (score 0):

Since it must be the case that `triggerFunction()` is called from another thread you may need a synchronised queue for your threads:

```py
from queue import Queue

class Sample(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        # some parts elided
        self.threadList = ... # Some threads created now?
        self.q = Queue()
    
    def run(self):        

        for trd in self.threadList:            
            trd.start()
            self.q.put(trd)
        self.threadList = None

        while not self.q.empty():
            trd = self.q.get()
            trd.join()
            
    def triggrFunction(self):
        #This function will be called through an event call
        
        # Do something
        
        # create a new thread
        trd = ...  
        self.q.put(trd)
```